# Как передать размеры из кода в xml

Tags: java, android

Суть вопроса - могу ли я из .java файла передать некие константы в xml файл, который связан с ним через setContentView(может быть это окажется важным).
Вот как я это имею ввиду
android:layout_marginTop="width" - переменная width должна быть получена из .java файла. Переменные в .java задаются в методе OnCreate(Это высота и ширина экрана)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Для чего это нужно? И давайте вопросу заголовок, отражающий вашу проблему, а не название главы в учебнике.

Comment: мне нужно чтобы отступы от краёв экрана, которые я задаю элементам, менялись в зависимости от размеров экрана. в коде я получаю эти размеры. Можно ли передать эти размеры в xml файл или нет?

Comment: Я вам дал ответ

Answer (score 1):

Установить параметры разметки в xml путём подстановки каких-то цифр в xml не сможете.  Там задаются параметры по умолчанию. Изменить эти параметры программно - без проблем. Читаете их из файла и устанавливаете.

Конкретизируйте вопрос, тогда будет более развернутый ответ